# mathcad adding two equations with one variable

Tags: mathcad

I checked this section for a similar question and could not locate one. It's simple one I'm guessing but I just cant figure it out.

Two equations:
3x^2 + 4x -7
and
5x^2-7x+3

(or whatever one variable equation).

How can I add them in mathcad so I get the answer 8x^2 -3x-4 ?

Thanks.
Mr Noob....

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, they both utilise the "Symbolic Evaluation" operator.

If you load Mathcad, define your functions as shown below.

[image: Symbolic]

To show the result of the addition, you need to use the "Symbolic Evaluation" operator which is located within the "Symbolic Evaluation Toolbar" as shown by this icon:

[image: Hat Icon]